# Ssh.net Conncetion timeout after 30000 milliseconds in Docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2, ssh.net

I am using Ssh.net nuget package in a .net core app to connect to remote Ubuntu servers on AWS.

I have dockerized my app and it works perfectly on local Windows envionment and a local ubuntu server.

Same docker image does not work if deployed on Aws Lightsail or other server providers like upcloud.com and vultr.com.

Below are the error details:

```
Connection failed to establish within 30000 milliseconds.
at Renci.SshNet.Abstractions.SocketAbstraction.Connect(IPEndPoint remoteEndpoint, TimeSpan connectTimeout) at Renci.SshNet.Session.SocketConnect(String host, Int32 port) at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect() at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
```

I have tried turning off firewalls on all of the tested platforms but it doesn't make a difference.

Any ideas what I should do to resolve the issue?

Comment: Have you tried making changes to the security workgroup in your AWS account? When it comes to connection issues on AWS for apps that work locally, Security workgroups are the first thing I like to see.

Comment: Yes, I have allowed all ports from all IPs in the used security workgroup. When I say it works locally, I mean, it connects to AWS server from my local machine. The local machine is out of AWS setup in a different region.

Comment: Are you using the IP address or DNS name in your app to connect to the Ubuntu Server?

Comment: That's actually a good point. I tried changing DNS name with IP but it did not work. My docker network is overlay. I have tried running .net core app without docker by directly running it as `dotnet run`. It works on local ubuntu server whrn I connect local server with AWS server but not on a cloud server.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time. The issue was that I was getting an "On" status from AWS Api but server was not still ready to connect via SSH. I have now put a timer to retry ssh connection every few seconds until it gets connected or my final timeout occurs.